# Electromagnetic Wave Direction Related to Change of Variables

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

So i'm doing some studying on electromagnetic waves and I've come to a halt in terms of all the directions.

So let's say that we have an EM wave given by these properties:

$$\vec{E}(t,z)=f(z+ct)+g(z-ct)$$
$$\vec{B}(t,z)=f(z+ct)-g(z-ct)$$

where $\vec{E}=(0,E,0)$ and $\vec{B}=(B,0,0)$. From what has been explained to me, the function $f(z+ct)$ is a leftward moving wave and $g(z-ct)$ is a rightward moving wave. To me, this means that the E and B fields are propagating outward in both the $z$ and $-z$ directions.

However, this is then put into the context of them being part of the EM wave, which was described as propagating only in the $+z$ direction. Again, I can understand this through the right-hand rule, where $\vec{B}\sim\hat{k}\times\vec{E}$. However, wouldn't this mean that for a wave propagating in the $+z$ direction, we would have

$$\vec{B}\sim\hat{k}\times\vec{E}=\hat{z}\times\hat{y}=-\hat{x}$$

This all fits mathematically, but when I look at images of EM waves, I find that the magnetic field is positive when the electric field is positive (for a rightward moving wave). Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: The image of an EM wave used on Wikipedia is correctly drawn, where did you see such an image?

Comment: From this image, I see a wave propagating in the x direction with E field in the z direction and B field in the y direction.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#/media/File:Onde_electromagnetique.svg  

Is this in left-handed orientation? If so, why in the world does Wikipedia use left-handed for all of its images?

Comment: This one is draw correctly though since $\hat{x}\times \hat{z}=\hat{y}$ which is the direction of B in the image. Did you mix up the colors or directions when trying the right hand rule?

Comment: But $\hat{x}\times\hat{z}=-\hat{y}$ in right-handed orientation?

Comment: Youre right that picture has me confused too.I think the source of the confusion is that the wave is drawn correctly but the axes are mislabeled, the picture is obviously right handed, there shouldn't be any doubt that it is. If you point your hands in the direction of travel then curl your fingers to E your thumb points along B. It's a right handed wave on a left handed coordinate system

Comment: Oh actually I see that this image is in a left-handed orientation, where $\hat{x}\times\hat{z}=\hat{y}$. The image makes sense to me now, but now I'm wondering why Wikipedia only seems to be using left-hand oriented EM waves.

Comment: Someone needs to correct the image by interchanging the x and y axes